# Replace NA with a date from another column and add 23:59:59 with it

Tags: r, datetime, replace, concatenation

I want to replace NA in a df column with date from another column + 23:59:59. Below is the sample data and my code. I'm facing issues in doing this. Any lights here..?

code:

```
df1[is.na(df1$start_time)] <- as.character(paste(dfs$Date,"23:59:59",sep=" "))

df1:

Date                start_time
5/30/2020                NA
5/30/2020         30/05/2020 07:33:12
5/30/2020                NA
5/30/2020         30/05/2020 09:33:12
```

Output needed:

```
  Date                start_time
5/30/2020          30/05/2020 23:59:59
5/30/2020          30/05/2020 07:33:12
5/30/2020          30/05/2020 23:59:59
5/30/2020          30/05/2020 09:33:12
```

Comment: Please follow Stack Overflow guidelines for proper data sharing and provide e.g. `dput(df1)`, read [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Is there a way to use dput(df[1:4, c(2, 15)]), so that I can produce the data in minimum with specific headers?

Comment: Why do you have different date format in `Date` column and `start_time` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using base R changing the `Date` column to "Date" class and "start_time" to `POSIXct`.

```
#Change to Date to date class
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
#Change start_time to POSIXct
df$start_time <- as.POSIXct(df$start_time, format = '%d/%m/%Y %T', tz = 'UTC')
#Find out NA indices
inds <- is.na(df$start_time)
#Replace the NA values taking Date and adding time as 23:59:59.
df$start_time[inds] <- as.POSIXct(paste0(df$Date[inds], '23:59:59'), "UTC")
df

#        Date          start_time
#1 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 23:59:59
#2 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 07:33:12
#3 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 23:59:59
#4 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 09:33:12
```

---

Similar way using `lubridate` functions :

```
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- mdy(df$Date)
df$start_time <- dmy_hms(df$start_time)
inds <- is.na(df$start_time)
df$start_time[inds] <- ymd_hms(paste0(df$Date[inds], '23:59:59'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("5/30/2020", "5/30/2020", "5/30/2020", 
"5/30/2020"), start_time = c(NA, "30/05/2020 07:33:12", NA, "30/05/2020 09:33:12"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind converting your columns in different formats to proper dates and times, you can use dplyr's [`coalesce()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) function along with lubridate's [durations](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/duration.html):

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date       = mdy(Date),
         start_time = coalesce(dmy_hms(start_time), Date + ddays(1) - dseconds(1)))
#>         Date          start_time
#> 1 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 23:59:59
#> 2 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 07:33:12
#> 3 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 23:59:59
#> 4 2020-05-30 2020-05-30 09:33:12
```

You simply convert the `Date` column with [`mdy()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html), and convert `start_time` column with [`dmy_hms()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd_hms.html) along with replacing all NAs by `Date` + 1 day - 1 second (i.e. [duration](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/duration.html) of 23:59:59).

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("5/30/2020", "5/30/2020", "5/30/2020", 
  "5/30/2020"), start_time = c(NA, "30/05/2020 07:33:12", NA, "30/05/2020 09:33:12"
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>